# Weird error in Airbrake, with UTF8 codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, hoptoad

I've recently encountered an error in Airbrake (ex Hoptoad).

The error read

```
%u672A%u5B9A%u7FA9%u306E%u30A8%u30E9%u30FC%u3067%u3059%u3002
```

I'm more used to errors like `NoMethodError: undefined method '-' for nil:NilClass`...

I haven't found a way to convert this to somehing more legible.

Do you know what this means? Should I be worried about that?
When I access the same URL, I don't get any error.

thanks!